# unarchiveObject(withFile) deprecated

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, deprecated, nskeyedunarchiver

I've been following this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html , which I know is old, but has been working fine.

However, I'm now getting the error messages about `archiveRootObject(_:toFile:)` and `unarchiveObject(withFile:)` are now deprecated.

I've followed an answer and I think I've sorted the archiveRootObject, but no idea how to do the unarchiveObject.

This is my updated archiveRootObject code:

```
do {
    let saveData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: meals, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    try saveData.write(to: Meal.ArchiveURL) }
catch { print(error) }
```

This is my original, now deprecated, unarchive code:

```
private func loadMeals() -> [Meal]? {

return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Meal] }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In that case your `Meal` class should conform to `NSSecureCoding` protocol (instead of `NSCoding`) and subclass `NSObject`:

```
class Meal: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {}
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {}
}
```

To unarchive the stored array of `Meal`s you can use `unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass:from:)` function, like this:

```
private func loadMeals() -> [Meal]? {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: Meal.ArchiveURL)
        return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: Meal.self, from: data)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```